# for-loop error in requirements (C)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

With the following code fragment, there's a problem with `i <= 5`, but can't quite figure it out. Is it supposed to be simply `i < 5`?

```
int i;
int array[5];
for (int = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
{
  array[i] = i/2
}
```

When entered as is, it returns

> "0, 1, 1, 2, 2"

When entered as `i < 5`, it returns

> "0, 1, 1, 2"

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 2):

if u declare array as arr[5] means ur array contains

```
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
arr[3]
arr[4]
```

so when you use `(i = 1 , i <= 5)` then ur array should print 5 elements

so when you use `(i = 1 , i < 5)` then ur array should print 4 elements one less as it is containing 5 elements

Comment: Actually, when you use `i <= 5` you write past the end of the array and with either segfault or corrupt whatever follows the array in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The array has 5 elements.  Since array starts from 0 you should set < 5 or <= 4. (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Thank you! I was considering that a problem but I am not too familiar with arrays.

Comment: You'll most often see the pattern of `for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`, which works well when you have a macro representing the number of elements in the array.  `for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i)`